# Подключить Wordpress API к скрипту PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Есть Wordpress и файл `api.php`

Требуется подключить функции wordpress к файлу `api.php`, чтобы оттуда можно было вызывать функции типа

```
$field = get_post_field( 324 );
echo $field;
```

и тд.

Собственно, как это сделать?

Погуглил и нашел этот вариант.
Но при вызове функции Wordpress выдает ошибку `HTTP 500 ERROR`:

```
<?php 

include_once 'wordpress/wp_load.php';

$field = get_post_field( 372 );
echo $field;
```

Comment: Подключение правильное, вызов get_post_field неправильный https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post_field

Comment: попробовал такой код 
$id = 423;
$post = get_post( $id );
echo $post->post_title;

всеравно выдает ошибку 500 http error

Comment: 500 ошибка может быть вызвана чем угодно. Включайте отладчик или хотя бы отладочную информацию в WP.

Comment: включил WP_DEBUG и все остальное, но к сожалению ошибок не наблюдается

Comment: а куда именно вставлять файл api ?
я вставил в папку с темой, вызываю его так
http://domainname/wordpress/wp-content/themes/example/test.php

Comment: да в общем-то все равно, лишь бы ссылки на папки были правильные оттуда. и, кстати, `include_once 'wordpress/wp_load.php'` оттуда работать не будет. Как минимум `include_once 'путь-к-папке/wordpress/wp_load.php' `

Comment: @S1lllver нужно смореть логи сервера, wp_debug тут мало чем сможет помочь. И путь к `wp_load.php` надо правильный указать. По тому что в вопросе api.php находиться выше `wordpress/wp_load.php`

Comment: И кстати можно по другому рабоать с ВП напр Rest-Api https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ Что же до ajax и пр js, то подключать скрипты нужно через [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). См: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: а туда можно подключить свой php скрипт ? кажется он только для javascript

Answer (score 1):

Укажите полный путь к файлу:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь все получилось.

Скидываем скрипт в папку темы, и пишем туда вот это.

Вот код :

```
<?php 

$path = preg_replace('/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/','',__DIR__);
include($path.'wp-load.php');
$post = get_post( 393 );
echo $post->post_title;

?>
```

Comment: столкнулся с очень странной ситуацией, пишу кому понадобиться может, через include_once вызов wp_load дает ошибку , а через обычный include все подключается без ошибок и проблем.

так что если появилась ошибка с include_once подключайте через include

Comment: Зачем  регулярки, чтобы узнать путь к файлу? о_0. Пропиши сразу нормально.

Comment: там преимущество в том что ненадо прописывать вручную, но я воспользовался способом который сам написал до этого, прописал просто include("../wp-load.php");

Comment: Что значит "вручную"? Можно прописать относительный путь, а можно использовать переменные php. Но вычислять регулярками..